# Ninja is required to load C++ extensions

Tags: python, ninja

I download a program and want to run it. It's from [github](https://github.com/zhanghang1989/PyTorch-Encoding).

I enter the experiments/segmentation/ folder, and input "python test.py --dataset PContext --model-zoo Encnet_ResNet50_PContext --eval" to the terminal.

The terminal shows "RuntimeError: Ninja is required to load C++ extensions. "
I have searched the Internet for a night but found no such questions.

Can anybody help me? It's my first time to come here to ask questions

Comment: I tried, no results. Maybe I need to compile something but  I don't know the characteristic of Ninja....

Comment: ninja-build.org, it is one executable, install it somewhere in your path

Answer (score 15):

I just had the same issue with my code. To solve it I installed ninja with pip :

```
pip install Ninja
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this error while trying to integrate deepspeed library into my training procedure.

`sudo apt-get install ninja-build`

fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/zhanghang1989/PyTorch-Encoding/issues/167#issuecomment-455296402) worked for me.

```
wget https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/releases/download/v1.10.2/ninja-linux.zip
sudo unzip ninja-linux.zip -d /usr/local/bin/
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ninja ninja /usr/local/bin/ninja 1 --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you install PyTorch?
Did you install PyTorch-Encoding?
(see https://hangzhang.org/PyTorch-Encoding/notes/compile.html)

You should install those packages (and all depencies are fetched automatically) with PIP. You can not just download the source and start! It is always a good idea to at least read the basic documentation of the package you are using.

Answer (score 0):

conda install conda

Environment Path for Ninja:

Even though Ninja is installed, it might not be properly recognized by your Python environment. Ensure that the Ninja executable is in your system's PATH or the environment's PATH. You can add it to the PATH using the Environment Variables settings in Windows.
Alternatively, try installing Ninja in the Anaconda environment directly